# Cakephp Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

How do I write the following query in cakephp format?

```sql
SELECT COUNT( ip_address ) AS num_values
FROM property_viewers
GROUP BY property_viewers.ip_address
ORDER BY property_viewers.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $this->model->find("count",array("fields"=>"ip_address",'group'=>'property_viewers.ip_address','order'=>'property_viewers.id DESC'))
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1018/find#find-count-1020

Answer (score 0):

```
 $options['fields'] = array("ip_address");
 $options['group']  = array("property_viewers.ip_address"); 
 $options['order']  = array('property_viewers.id DESC');
 $this->model->find("count",$options);
```

By using this you dont have to worry about nested arrays